# Code::Blocks debugger won't start (Inferior 1 exited normally)

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

So i can't make Code::Blocks start debugging my program. This actually happened before but i'm able to fix it by removing blank space and special characters in my project directory name. However for some reason that i'm not aware of, now even with correct directory name i can't start debugging my program. I've tried enabling -g in compiler settings but not the -s.

This is the full log of the debugger.

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: D:\semester3\Strukdat\project\tugasindividu_soal1\lol\
Adding source dir: D:\semester3\Strukdat\project\tugasindividu_soal1\lol\
Adding file: D:\semester3\Strukdat\project\tugasindividu_soal1\lol\bin\Debug\lol.exe
Changing directory to: D:/semester3/Strukdat/project/tugasindividu_soal1/lol/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\FPC\3.0.4\bin\i386-Win32;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\fairuz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\fairuz\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32

[debug]Command-line: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args D:/semester3/Strukdat/project/tugasindividu_soal1/lol/bin/Debug/lol.exe
[debug]Working dir : D:\semester3\Strukdat\project\tugasindividu_soal1\lol

Starting debugger: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args D:/semester3/Strukdat/project/tugasindividu_soal1/lol/bin/Debug/lol.exe
done

[debug]> set prompt >>>>>>cb_gdb:

Setting breakpoints

[debug]Reading symbols from D:/semester3/Strukdat/project/tugasindividu_soal1/lol/bin/Debug/lol.exe...done.
[debug](gdb) >>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> show version
[debug]GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
[debug]Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[debug]License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[debug]This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
[debug]There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
[debug]and "show warranty" for details.
[debug]This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
[debug]Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
[debug]For bug reporting instructions, please see:
[debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
[debug]Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
[debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
[debug]For help, type "help".
[debug]Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set confirm off

Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1

[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set width 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set height 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set breakpoint pending on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print asm-demangle on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set unwindonsignal on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print elements 200
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set new-console on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set disassembly-flavor att
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> catch throw
[debug]Catchpoint 1 (throw)
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> directory D:/semester3/Strukdat/project/tugasindividu_soal1/lol/
[debug]Source directories searched: D:/semester3/Strukdat/project/tugasindividu_soal1/lol;$cdir;$cwd
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> break "D:/semester3/Strukdat/Fromfrends/2_createHuffTree&huffCode/huffTree&Code.c:54"
[debug]No source file named D:/semester3/Strukdat/Fromfrends/2_createHuffTree&huffCode/huffTree&Code.c.
[debug]Breakpoint 2 ("D:/semester3/Strukdat/Fromfrends/2_createHuffTree&huffCode/huffTree&Code.c:54") pending.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> run
[debug]Starting program: D:\semester3\Strukdat\project\tugasindividu_soal1\lol\bin\Debug\lol.exe 

Child process PID: 24828

[debug][New Thread 24828.0x9bc]
[debug][New Thread 24828.0x586c]
[debug][Thread 24828.0x586c exited with code 0]
[debug][Inferior 1 (process 24828) exited normally]
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:

[Inferior 1 (process 24828) exited normally]

[debug]> quit

Debugger finished with status 0
```

Can anyone spot what i did wrong?

I guess it must be because

```
[debug]No source file named D:/semester3/Strukdat/Fromfrends/2_createHuffTree&huffCode/huffTree&Code.c.
```

But i have no idea what to do with that information.

Comment: Could you try to use file and folder names without special characters like `&` in their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone spot what i did wrong?

According to Code::Blocks [documentation](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks#Path_with_spaces) there should be no special characters in file or folder names in your project:

> Breakpoints could not work if the path/folder you've placed your project contains spaces or other special characters. To be safe use English letters, digits and '_'.

You have 2 `&` characters in a path to file `D:/semester3/Strukdat/Fromfrends/2_createHuffTree&huffCode/huffTree&Code.c`. I'd suggest to remove them or substitute with `_`.